# Python Pandas Frequency documentation

Tags: python, pandas

I have been trying to get a proper documentation for the freq arguments associated with pandas. For example to resample a dataframe we can do something like

```
df.resample(rule='W', how='sum')
```

which will resample this weekly. I was wondering what are the other options and how can I define custom frequency/rules.

**EDIT** : To clarify I am looking at what are the other legal options for `rule`

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects

Comment: Thanks i have looked at it. It gives some examples such as ``asfreq='D'`` but not the documentation for legal values of ``asfreq``

Comment: look down about 2 screenfulls worth: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#offset-aliases. You should read this entire section.

Comment: Sorry about that Jeff. I accepted a similar answer by @U2EF1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#offset-aliases

And, almost immediately below that: [W-SAT and others](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#anchored-offsets).

I'll admit, links to this particular piece of documentation are pretty scarce. More general frequencies can be represented by supplying a `DateOffset` instance. Even more general resamplings can be done via `groupby`.

Comment: I guess I wasn't too clear..

so the part I want to see is the options for rule

as per the doc link it just says:

rule : string
the offset string or object representing target conversion

i was trying to look at a comprehensive list of all such rules and if we can define custom rules

Comment: btw yup i do it by groupby for now, but am trying to understand what I can do by resample only

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I upvoted it as its towards the ans i am looking for. So the one thing missing from that table is the fact that I have seen people using ``W-Sat`` and so on. Any clues to these kind of asfreq?

Comment: @goofd Also on that page. Really the whole page is worth a read, it's full of goodies.

Comment: my bad. i have been to that page many times but some how i always missed it !!